# Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class purrweb\heroku\HerokuGeneratorController does not exist'

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to deploy the yii2 app on Heroku what I have tried so far is this.

I have changed the code of `console/config/main-local.php:` In at this way.

```
'controllerMap' => [
        'heroku' => [
            'class' => 'purrweb\heroku\HerokuGeneratorController',
        ],
    ],
```

I have saved the file and in terminal, I have executed the following command.

```
php yii heroku
```

but it has given me this error.

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class purrweb\heroku\HerokuGeneratorController does not exist'
```

Comment: Does the given class exist after all? Whats the reason for changing that code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to upload the same in Heroku one tutorial suggests that this is the way to do that that's the reason which I have tried to do the same.

Comment: Following this tutorial https://github.com/PurrWeb/yii2-heroku